# Calling lists from option_lists (tkinter and python)

Tags: python, list, tkinter, widget

When using .get(the tkinter function thingy) it seems to turn the lists into strings. When looking around it seems there isn't any real way of using option list to select lists without going

```
if variable.get = list_1 list_choice = list_1
elif varible.et = list_2 list _choice = list_2
ect
```

but that would mean when adding new lists I have add more elifs and that I couldn't add new lists when running the code (I think)

Any ideas on how to use .get to  call a list from a input widget?

thanks for any input or even just reading this over!

code:

```
list_1 = ["list 1",[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],0.9,[0.5,2],[0.5,2.5,10],[10,5],[0,0,0,1]]
list_2 = ["list 2",[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],1,[1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
list_3 = ["list 3",[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],0,[0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
  
#creates the drop down list
OptionList = [
list_1[0:1],
list_2[0:1],
list_3[0:1] 
] 

app = tk.Tk()

app.geometry('100x200')

variable = tk.StringVar(app)
variable.set(OptionList[0])
print(OptionList[0])
opt = tk.OptionMenu(app, variable, *OptionList)
opt.config(width=90, font=('Helvetica', 12))
opt.pack(side="top")



def callback(*args):
    global list_1 
    global list_2
    ##removes extra string stuff
    list_choice= variable.get().replace(",", "")
    list_choice= aid.replace("(", "")
    list_choice= aid.replace(")", "")
    list_choice= aid.replace(" ", "_")
    list_choice= aid.replace("'", "")
    print(list_choice)
    list_choice= vars()[list_choice]
    print(list_choice)
    print(list_choice[2:2])
```